# Can you become a commercial airline pilot in Europe while being monocular

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, airline-pilot

I’m not sure if I could get a EASA medical class 1 while being monocular. But I think that you can get a soda in the us and I want to know, if I could take a FAA medical class 1 and then fly in Europe with a FAA. Or even better if I could get a soda in Europe and get a EASA medical class 1, and become a commercial airline pilot in Europe while being monocular.

I know this has been asked before but that only covers about getting the license, and I want to know if I could get a soda.

Answer (score 0):

Pilot certificates don't give you permission to fly in a location, they give you permission to fly an airplane registered by that authority anywhere in the world. In other words, if you have an FAA pilot certificate you can fly a US registered airplane no matter where it is. If you have an FAA ATPL and appropriate class of medical you can work for any airline that flies US registered airplanes. The same is true for any licensing authority.

The reverse is not true, you could not get a FAA certificate and fly a UK registered airplane, for example, even if it was in the US. There are some cases where you can get a local certificate on the basis of another equivalent certificate, but I believe you always need to be able to pass the local medical.

Comment: There some who says that I could fly in Europe and I’m not sure if I would be able to fly a European registered airplane. Does anyone know if I could get a soda in Europe.

Comment: There's no such thing as a european registered airplane, every country has its own aviation authority that registers airplanes and issues licences/certificates, including medical certificates. Many countries are part of EASA, however you have to look at it in a country by country basis.

Comment: But can I get a soda in Europe and if not could I then take a FAA with a soda and fly in European airspace.

Comment: If you can get a licensing authority to issue you with a medical certificate and you get a pilots license from that authority then you can fly an airplane registered with that authority, it doesn't matter where it is.

Comment: Can you get a soda in Europe like the us

Comment: It depends on the authority, and the class you are going for. I don't know, honestly.

Comment: GdD, I think you're close to right about not being able to fly a UK registered airplane with an FAA pilot certificate. But, there is an exception: you can fly it in the U.S. An FAA pilot certificate allows you to fly any airplane in the U.S. (as long as it's legal to fly it in the U.S. at all), regardless of its country of registration.